# While is my TailwindCSS Responsive Design not working?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have this NextJS project and which I am using both Boostrap and TailwindCSS, but I added a prefix to my Tailwind codes with "tw-". For some whatever reason, the responsive codes for Tailwind is not applying.

Here is a code I need to make the Image smaller on mobile:

```
return (
    <div>
        <nav className="bg-light tw-h-[65px] tw-w-full shadow-lg d-flex tw-items-center">
               <AiOutlineMenuUnfold size="2.5rem"/>
            <h4 className="text-primary">Welcome: Tombrown Anuma</h4>
        </nav>
        <Image className="tw-sm:w-[5rem] tw-md:w-[10rem] tw-rounded-full float-end tw-mt-[-3rem]" alt="profile-image" src={ProfilePic}/>
    </div>
);
```

Note: everything else is working is intended except the responsive codes.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix), the "prefix is added *after* any variant modifiers":

```
<Image className="sm:tw-w-[5rem] md:tw-w-[10rem] tw-rounded-full float-end tw-mt-[-3rem]" alt="profile-image" src={ProfilePic}/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but still didn't work

Comment: Consider checking Tailwind has run a compilation since you added the classes, the file that the source code is in is covered by the `content` file globs, `sm` and `md` exist as `screens` values, the browser state matches the `sm` or `md` media queries, the `width` or `height` core Tailwind plugins have not been disabled and whether some other CSS might be overriding the Tailwind rules.